# Get all user into subOus in a OU java ldap

Tags: java, ldap

i'm trying to search all user into a OU="Usuarios", but OU="Usuarios" have a subOus, example :

OU=Usuarios
    user :ivan 
    OU:Gerentes
       user:pablo

my problem :

i need to find the user ivan and pablo. but the result is comming only with ivan.

the code :

```
SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
String consulta = "(& (objectClass=user))";
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> renum = context.search("OU=Usuarios," + toDC(dominio),
                    consulta, controls);
```

I want to do this recursively, not put ("OU=Gerentes,OU=Usuarios Rimac) .

How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide more information as to you LDAP server and DIT structure.

Answer (score 0):

does your directory tree hiearachy look like this

```
ou=Usarios
|     - ivan
|
+ou=Gerentes
      - pablo
```

you should be able to construct your search at a base of `ou=Usarios` and get everything below in including the sub ou's with a scope of `SUBTREE_SCOPE`.

A filter like `(&(objectclass=user)(|(uid=ivan)(uid=pablo)))` should find both ivan and pablo if you begin your search high enough with a scope of of `SUBTREE_SCOPE`.

If you want all users your search string should just be `(objectclass=user)`.

One thing the search base need to be fully qualified from the root.  This would typically be something like

```
ou=Usarios,dc=company,dc=com
```

Comment: just realized `toDC(dominio)` IS the domain component(s) - sorry.